# Click event newly created extended vertical lines in chart js

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

good day i am adding a new features to add vertical lines on chart js and I successeded in that but I want to attach click event for the new rectangle or the newly created line but this was difficult for me could you give me a hand

```
let originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.line.prototype, {
  name: "JobLine",
  
  draw: function () {
    originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);

    let chart = this.chart;
    let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = chart.chart.ctx;
    let x = chart.chart.width / 2;      
    let data = chart.config.data.lineAtIndex;
    let labels: any[] = chart.config.data.labels;

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i]) {
        let index = labels.indexOf(data[i].value);

        let xaxis = chart.scales["x-axis-0"];
        let yaxis = chart.scales["left-y-axis"];

        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.top);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#f20ef2";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;

        ctx.lineTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.bottom);
        ctx.setLineDash([10, 10]);

        ctx.rotate(-0.5 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(
          yaxis.top - 60,
          xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index) - 20,
          25,
          20
        );

        // draw font in red
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.font = "10pt arial";
        ctx.fillText(
          data[i].text,
          yaxis.top - 60 + 2,
          xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index) - 20 + 10
        );
        this.clicked = function () {
          alert(data[i].text);
        };
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.restore();
      }
    }
  },
```